# What is the meaning of following syntax:: fstream myFile("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
fstream myFile("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

How is this line interpreted by the compiler in C++ file handling?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about that statement? What part *exactly* are you wondering about? What does your text-books say? What kind of research have you done? Or perhaps you need to invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to begin with?

Comment: Illustrate using suitable example, why friend function in needed for operator overloading when 
you can achieve the same using member function.

This is the complete question @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information. Also please take some time to refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Presumably, these names are intended to be `std::fstream`, `std::ios::in`, `std::ios::out`, and `std::ios::trunc`. As written, they have no intrinsic meaning.

Answer (score 2):

`ios::out` means that you intend to write to the file in contrast to reading `ios::in`. In your case the stream can be used for both reading and writing.

`ios::trunc` means that the current file content will be discarded. Compare this to `ios::app` where you will append to a file if it exists. `ios::trunc` is implied if not `ios::in` is specified for example. ["When used for an ofstream without ios::app, ios::ate or ios::in, ios::trunc is implied."](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_080.html)

Bonus:

`iso::binary` means that what you will write will be put verbatim into the file (otherwise for windows `\n` could be replaced with `\n\r` for example)

Answer (score 0):

**fstream** : This data type represents the file stream generally, and has the capabilities of both ofstream and ifstream which means it can create files, write information to files, and read information from files.

Also it using multiple flags as per below:

**ios::app** : Append mode. All output to that file to be appended to the end.

**ios::ate** : Open a file for output and move the read/write control to the end of the file.

**ios::in**  : Open a file for reading.

**ios::out** : Open a file for writing.

**ios::trunc** : If the file already exists, its contents will be truncated before opening the file.

in your case text.txt file will open for reading, writing and if exists then content will truncated.